# How to find a Möbius transformation given three points and their images

Tags: mobius-transformation

I want to find the Möbius transformation $f$ such that

$f(0)=0,f(1)=1,f(\dfrac12+\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i)=(0.4387+0.759775 \ i)$

Is this possible? I tried both cross ratios and systems of equation approaches but I can't find any solution. Thanks for helps.

Comment: The proof of the action being transitive is constructive... So you know the cross ratios should work. I imagine it's a typo?

Comment: Just a note: Yes it's possible, and yes, there's a unique Mobius transformation that fixes $0$ and $1$ and sends that sixth root of unity to an arbitrary complex number distinct from $0$ and $1$. (Offhand I'd try to write down the general transformation that fixes $0$ and $1$; there should be a single complex parameter remaining.)

Comment: @mdave16 I ended up understanding your first sentence (but I don't think it's understandable by an undergraduate student). But I still don't understand where you see a typo...

Comment: First sentence: note that the action of mobius tranforms on the riemann sphere is nice i.e. given any two triples of distinct pts, there is a tranform going from one to the other. The proof of this is constructive, and uses cross ratios. Thus, using cross ratios to solve the problem should (and will) work. If OP truly did try it and didnt get it, I imagine there is a typo in their working.  It would be similar to using the quadratic formula to solve a quadratic, but not getting any solutions... you've just entered the formula wrong on a calc.

Answer (score 2):

A general Möbius transformation has the form $T(z) = (az+b)/(cz+d)$, and we can take $ad-bc=1$. If $T(0)=0$, we have
$$0=\frac{b}{d},$$
so $b=0$ (and $d \neq 0$, or $T(0) = \infty)$. Hence $a \neq 0$, so divide by it and look for $T(z) = 1/(Cz+D) $.

$T(1)=1$, so
$$ 1 = \frac{1}{C+D}. $$
or
$$ C+D=1.  \tag{1}$$
Finally, if you want to send $\alpha$ to $\beta$, you need
$$ \beta = \frac{\alpha}{C\alpha+D},  $$
or
$$ C\alpha+D=\frac{\alpha}{\beta} \tag{2} $$
You can then solve (1) and (2) simultaneously, which will work since $\alpha \neq 1$. You'll find
$$ T(z) = \frac{(1-\alpha)z}{(1-\beta/\alpha)z+(\beta/\alpha-\alpha)}. $$